# Form logic works in Chrome, not in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have a basic HTML form with a input field that I want to start disabled but change to enabled based on a previous select input. This works in Chrome but fails in IE... probably something stupidly easy but I cannot find a solution..

```
<script language="javascript">
function enableFeedback(val)
{
    if(val == "Feedback"){
    document.frmQuestionnaire.txtAns3.disabled=false;
}
else {
    document.frmQuestionnaire.txtAns3.value="";
    document.frmQuestionnaire.txtAns3.disabled=true;

}
}
</script>

<td valign="top" colspan="3"><select name="select" onChange="enableFeedback(this.value)">
            <option>Select an option...</option>
            <option>Feedback</option>
            <option>No feedback</option>
    </select></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="92" bgcolor="#ffffff"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Comments:</font></td>
    <td valign="top" colspan="3"><input name="txtAns3" size="6" disabled="disabled"></td>
```

Comment: Basic JS has methods like `getElementById()` and `getElementsByName()`, use them instead of direct references, which has been deprecated over a decade ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script language="javascript">
function updateFeedback(val)
{
val=+val;
var txtElem = document.getElementById("txtAns3");
txtElem.disabled=val?"":"disabled";
val||(txtElem.value="");
}
</script>

<td valign="top" colspan="3">
<select name="select" onChange="updateFeedback(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
            <option value="0">Select an option...</option>
            <option value="1">Feedback</option>
            <option value="0">No feedback</option>
    </select></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left" width="92" bgcolor="#ffffff"><font size="2" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Comments:</font></td>
    <td valign="top" colspan="3">
    <input id="txtAns3" name="txtAns3" size="6" disabled></td>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! This enabled the form field when I selected either Feedback or No feedback. I'm trying to get the form field to only be enabled when Feedback is selected...

Comment: I think I follow the logic, I just don't quite understand val||(txtElem.value="");

Comment: Thank you so much for the help on this. I do think I understand now, and this works perfectly. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: @MattH You're welcome :)
In JavaScript, the binary operators' trick is to judge the outcome by looking at the first input, for example:
`a && b = function(a,b){if(a)return a else return b}`
This works well for boolean values, but is also good for other expressions:
`if(abc)functioncall();` is equivalent to `abc&&functioncall();` (at least in what it does, not returns)
`abc||(abc="default")` is used to set default values.
In this case, it's `if(!val)txtElem.value=""`